# Отправка на сервер GET запроса с содержанием кириллицы

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c, кириллица

Проблема следующего характера. Я отправляю на сервер запрос методом GET

```
phoneV = _textVPhone.text;
passwordV = _textVPas.text;

NSString *urlConnect = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://mangashow.ru/test/fri/user_login_gai.php?kod=19&phone=%@&password=%@", phoneV, passwordV];
// Создать запрос.
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlConnect]];
NSLog(@"адрес подключения: %@", request);
// Создать соединение и послать запрос
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Никаких проблем не возникает пока я не вставляю в адрес запроса кириллицу.
Но как только в переменной passwordV оказваются русскоязычные слова. (Эта же переменная потом вставляется в url, значения в саму переменную вставляются из  Text Viled, ) то в request у меня получается null и соответственно запрос уходит в никуда.
Вот данные логов:

1. когда все нормально

   <NSURLRequest: 0x7f7fed150b90> { URL: http://mangashow.ru/test/fri/user_login_gai.php?kod=19&phone=80890809&password=admin }
2. И когда в запросе кириллица

   2016-02-21 15:12:30.560 gai.net[10440:279246] адрес подключения: <NSURLRequest: 0x7f7fea52be50> { URL: (null) }

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, напрягая головной процессор и строку запроса от яндекса, проблема решилась. Дело в том, что я совсем забыл про кодировку отправляемого запроса, вот и работал нормально только при латинице.
Для того что бы отправить кириллицу в запросе надо добавить:

```
urlConnect = [urlConnect stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Может кому пригодиться.